# how do i ask the user for a password with a capital in it python

Tags: python, validation, capitalize

I am trying to ask the user for a password, I can validate the length but I don't know how to ask for a capital letter in their password.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way to do it is to see whether the password changes when you make it all lower case:

```
if password.lower() == password:
    print('Password rejected - needs a capital letter!')
```

You could also do it with regex (in case you didn't have enough problems already):

```
import re
# if you're just looking at one at a time
if not re.search('[A-Z]', password):
    print('Password rejected etc.')

# if you're probably looking at many
regex = re.compile('[A-Z]')
if not regex.search(password):
    print('Password rejected etc.')
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do a `set` intersection with the letters in `string.ascii_uppercase`:

```
import string

def validate(pw):
    return len(pw) >= 8 and set(string.ascii_uppercase).intersection(pw)
```

That code returns the set, which will be truthy if it is not empty (that is, the password contained at least one uppercase ASCII letter). You may also need to test for lowercase letters, which you can do with another set intersection, this time with a set built from `string.ascii_lowercase`.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the string and check if any character is uppercase

```
def checkCapital(password):
    for x in password:
        if 'A'<=x<='Z':
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: This works but isn't as explicit as checking for `x.isupper()`, in my opinion.

Comment: Using list comprehension, you could do `[x for x in password if x.isupper()]`. That gives you a list of characters that are uppercase and is falsy if there are no uppercase characters.

Comment: The more idiomatic form of this would be `return any(c.isupper() for c in password)`